# How to get the width/height of the screen on Tizen

Tags: html, tizen, tizen-web-app

I wonder if there is any possibility to obtain the height and the width of the emulator screen using the Tizen IDE for web applications.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can use below method to get the values in a web app.

```
tizen.systeminfo.getPropertyValue("DISPLAY", function(disp) {
            $("#resWidth").html(disp.resolutionWidth);
            $("#resHeight").html(disp.resolutionHeight);
            $("#dpiWidth").html(disp.dotsPerInchWidth);
            $("#dpiHeight").html(disp.dotsPerInchHeight);
            $("#physWidth").html(disp.physicalWidth);
            $("#physHeight").html(disp.physicalHeight);
        });
```

Comment: I was also stuck with how to get screen width/height. Thanks for the answer @Srabani Patra.

Answer (score 0):

Or using the [Screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen):

```
console.log(screen.height);
console.log(screen.width);
```